# html grows vertical margin on touch screens

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site with a really weird issue.

the template on touch screens has a really large vertical margin out of the viewport
this margin doesn't exist when I use responsive browser simulation unless I **activate touch simulation** then somehow the page grows that large margin.

I've been poking around the inspector trying to find out which element is causing this issue but with no luck!

I even used `overflow-x:hidden`, `max-width:100%` and `max-width:100vw` and nothing seems to work.

here's the link hopefully someone can point out what my eyes are missing

[طريقة قياس (طريقة-قياس-قيمة-مسافة-الحدقة-قيمة-ipd-الع)](https://blog.miraatoptical.com/%d8%b7%d8%b1%d9%8a%d9%82%d8%a9-%d9%82%d9%8a%d8%a7%d8%b3-%d9%82%d9%8a%d9%85%d8%a9-%d9%85%d8%b3%d8%a7%d9%81%d8%a9-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%ad%d8%af%d9%82%d8%a9-%d9%82%d9%8a%d9%85%d8%a9-ipd-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b9/)

*irrelevant note: the site is in the Arabic language*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this may seem a little bit missy but as a quick solution I fixed the problem by adding this code in a media query.

```
html {
    width: 100vw !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Let me know if it works bro.

BS: the elements that are out of proportion is the navbar and the scroll to top [as per attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mji6o.png) so if you want a clean fix then fix their CSS as they are the root of your problem

Comment: Thank you so much man! I've been trying to do that on the body element but apparently  it should've been on html element. Honestly the messy fix is exactly what i needed since i had no plan to fix the template rather than fixing the appearance itself